# Sort array on the basis of the last word of string

Tags: ruby, string, sorting

I have an array like:

```
[
 "https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650497/img_0_0_0.jpg",
 "https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650510/img_0_0_20.jpg",
 "https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650499/img_0_0_10.jpg",
 "https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650521/img_0_0_30.jpg", 
 "https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650498/img_0_0_1.jpg",
 "https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650522/img_0_0_31.jpg"
]
```

I want to sort it on the basis of the last word of the string after `"/"`, which is the `"img_0_0"` word. But I cannot find any solution to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "the last word"? Is `"img_0_0_0.jpg"` a word? In what sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To order as strings:

```
> puts urls.sort_by { |u| u.split('/').last }
https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650497/img_0_0_10.jpg
https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650510/img_0_0_2.jpg
https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650499/img_0_1_1.jpg
```

To order by the numbers "naturally":

```
> puts urls.sort_by { |u| u.split('/').last.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) }
https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650510/img_0_0_2.jpg
https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650497/img_0_0_10.jpg
https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650499/img_0_1_1.jpg
```

Comment: Best one . Thanks Sir (Y)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
array.sort_by do |item| 
  item.match(/\/img_(\d)+_(\d+)_(\d+).jpg$/).captures.map(&:to_i)
end
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/repls/AggravatingCreativeAmphiuma)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you expect the items to be sorted in *numerical* order, so that `img_0_0_9` comes before `img_0_0_10`. To do so, we extract the suffix of the `img` part of all items, convert them to numeric values and sort the array accordingly:

```
arr.sort_by { |e| e[%r|(?<=/img_0_0_).*(?=\.jpg\z)|].to_i }

#⇒ [
#   [0] "https://ya.../img_0_0_0.jpg",
#   [1] "https://ya.../img_0_0_1.jpg",
#   [2] "https://ya.../img_0_0_10.jpg",
#   [3] "https://ya.../img_0_0_20.jpg",
#   [4] "https://ya.../img_0_0_30.jpg",
#   [5] "https://ya.../img_0_0_31.jpg"
# ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution

```
arr.sort{ |x, y| x.split('/')[-1].gsub('.jpg', '') <=> y.split('/')[-1].gsub('.jpg', '') }
```

Comment: DRY: `arr.sort { |x, y| [x, y].map { |e| e.split('/').sub(/\.jpg\z/, '') }.reduce(:<=>) }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
links = [
  "https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650497/img_0_0_0.jpg",
  "https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650510/img_0_0_20.jpg",
  "https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650499/img_0_0_10.jpg",
  "https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650521/img_0_0_30.jpg",
  "https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650498/img_0_0_1.jpg",
  "https://yallamotor-development-assets.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2650522/img_0_0_31.jpg"]

links.sort_by do |link|
  link.last(12)
      .split('')
      .map {|x| Integer(x) rescue nil }
      .compact
      .join
      .to_i
end
```

This takes the last 12 characters from each array and takes every number on it, convert it to integer, and then sort it